# Docker custom run params on compose file

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose

I need to run a docker container using this command

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 --memory 4g --cpus 4 \
https://endpoint \
Eula=accept \
Billing={ENDPOINT_URI} \
ApiKey={API_KEY}
```

But I need to run it via a docker compose file, and can't manage to set the parameters Eula, Billing and ApiKey.
Any hints on how that could be achieved?

Comment: just add them to your `command: ` service parameter in your compose file as is done in your example docker command. Meanwhile, showing what you have already tried and details about the exact problem you're having would probably help to get a meaningful answer (and keep your question open).

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks, it worked for me. I've edited the question with the code that solved it for me

Comment: Great, thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work with @Zeitounator suggestion

The docker compose file end looking like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  scriptme-ml-model:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/speechservices/speech-to-text
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    deploy:
        resources:
            limits:
              cpus: 2
              memory: 2g
            reservations:
              cpus: 2
              memory: 2g
    command: >
      Eula=accept
      Billing={ENDPOINT_URI}
      ApiKey={API_KEY}
```